# setsockopt usage in Linux and Solaris [Invalid argument in Solaris]

Tags: c, linux, sockets, solaris

I'm trying to use `setsockopt()` on both Linux and Solaris in my ftp program.

Linux uses a `long` for `optvalue` as a parameter, but Solaris uses a `char` instead.

```
#ifdef sun
    char val;
#else
    long val;
#endif

#ifdef sun
    val = 1;
    size_t len = sizeof(char);
    if(setsockopt(s_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, len) == -1) {
        perror("Fail");
        exit(1);
    }
#else
    val = 1;
    size_t len = sizeof(long);
    if(setsockopt(s_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, len) == -1) {
        perror("Fail");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif
```

The program works fine in Linux, but reports "Invalid argument" in Solaris when creating the socket.

Comment: Use the number `1`, not the character `'1'`.

Comment: Seems like the optvalue for solaris is  a character '1'.

Comment: I saw it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592747/bind-error-while-recreating-socket

Comment: It's incorrect.  You use `char` for the type, but the value is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error message happen :(

Comment: BTW, the second `#ifdef` is unnecessary if you write `size_t len = sizeof val;`, to use the already-selected type.

Comment: What version of Solaris?  How are you compiling and linking your program?  If you're linking with `-lxnet` and not `-lsocket -lnsl`, the prototype is `int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name,
     const void* option_value, socklen_t option_len);`  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/setsockopt-3xnet.html#scrolltoc  (And if you look in Solaris 11's `/usr/include/sys/socket.h`, you'd see that's the prototype anyway - because with C, you can pass a `char *` to a `void *` and an `int` to a `socklen_t` without error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues appearing in the question:

- > Linux uses a `long` for optvalue as a parameter, but Solaris uses a `char`
  >   instead.

TL;DR: you should use `int` everywhere.

in Solaris there can be slightly different definitions of `setsockopt()` depending on the version of Solaris and the library the program is linked against, for example Solaris 10's [setsockopt (3SOCKET)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5170/setsockopt-3socket.html), [setsockopt (3XNET)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5170/setsockopt-3xnet.html) and Solaris 11's [setsockopt (3SOCKET)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/getsockopt-3socket.html), [setsockopt (3XNET)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/setsockopt-3xnet.html). [Linux' manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) shares the same contents as Solaris' (3SOCKET) manpages:

> Most socket-level options utilize an **int** argument for optval. For
>   setsockopt(), the argument should be nonzero to enable a boolean
>   option, or zero if the  option is to be disabled.

(3XNET) just doesn't state the type for bolean option. Yet-an-other-UNIX (AIX) also has old *BSD and UNIX98/XOPEN versions, on a [single page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/ssocko.htm), where it's an `int` for booleans. The confusion about using `char` comes from (*BSD-style) examples using a pointer cast to `(char *)` instead of `(const void *)`, because the prototype is using `char *` for *BSD/3XNET. That doesn't mean the parameter is `char`. As for `long`, beside not being in the definition, on architectures where [`long` is not `int`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) that would be wrong. Note that Windows is apart from *NIX there.

- > ```
  > size_t len = sizeof(char);
  > ```

Beside the fact that `sizeof val` should be preferred, and can be used directly in `setsockopt()` without even the need to use `len` here in the first place, `len` is defined as `int` on Solaris (3XNET) and as `socklen_t` on Solaris (3SOCKET) and Linux, not `size_t` anywhere. [Link to a possible explanation](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/socklen_t.html) on why `int` became `socklen_t` with a brief (and wrong) passage via `size_t`. Using other types (such as `size_t` on Linux) might break on some architectures when `size_t` is not defined as `int` (see the 2 previous links).

Comment: Solaris provides *two* `setsockopt()` function calls, depending on whether or not the program links with `-lsocket -lnsl` or with `-lxnet`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/setsockopt-3socket.html#scrolltoc and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/setsockopt-3xnet.html#scrolltoc

Comment: This link is better:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5170/setsockopt-3socket.html  (that's an old Solaris 10 man page for `setsockopt.3socket`).  The 3xnet entry is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5170/setsockopt-3xnet.html  On Solaris 11, the prototypes both use `void *` and `socklen_t`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll update my answer to state that Solaris 11 has the same defintions with your 2nd link. AND I'll correct a mistake I made: setsockopt() doesn't take a pointer to the size (len), only getsockopt() does

Comment: If you have access to Solaris 10, it'd be interesting to see what's in `/usr/include/sys/socket.h` there.  All I have access to is OpenSolaris and Solaris 11, which all use the later, POSIX-compliant prototype.  POSIX made quite a mess in this case, IMO.

Comment: Actually accès to none, I stopped being in contact with Solaris after Solaris 8. My answer required more historical dig and verifications than anything else. The Oracle documentation should be enough about the len type? It's more about the canonical way to pass a boolean for the value in (3XNET) that isn't that well defined.

Comment: I just looked into `/usr/include/sys/socket.h` on a Solaris 10 system.  There are numerous variations on `#if defined(_XPG4_2)` and `#if defined(_XPG5)` in the header, changing among other things function prototypes.  The OP really needs to look into how his code is compiled and linked to ensure it's all consistent.